# AmbiguousMatchException thrown for different bodies

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

I have two forms that post to the same URL: `http://localhost/foo/bar`

```html
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/foo/bar">
    <input name="someId" value="123" />
</form>

<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/foo/bar">
    <input name="someData" value="345435435" />
</form>
```

And I have the following actions in the `FooController`:

```c#
[HttpPost("bar")]
public IActionResult A([FromForm] string someId)
{
    ...
}

[HttpPost("bar")]
public IActionResult B([FromForm] string someData)
{
    ...
}
```

But I'm getting an `AmbiguousMatchException`. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Could you consider having a single method with two parameters? Then branch as needed inside the method.

Comment: Yeah I could, and that's what I'll end up doing if I can't have 2 actions, but I thought having 2 actions would be cleaner.

Comment: FWIW, it's generally preferable to branch in the action an call out to private methods. That achieves the same goal (keeping the code branches separate), but still leaves you with just a single endpoint. While something like `ParameterContraint` attribute solves this limited use case, it won't solve every need of this kind, and it also makes your code harder to understand, even if only minutely. Though, if you do this type of stuff quite often, it can become exponentially harder to trace where requests are going.

Comment: Additionally, while it's not quite as important with MVC as it is with an API, it still is preferable to follow REST guidelines, which would dictate that two types of requests necessitates two URLs.

Comment: I agree with that but unfortunately we sometimes have to deal with third parties that don't follow the guidelines

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with an attribute!

```c#
public class ParameterConstraint : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public ParameterConstraint(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(RouteContext routeContext, ActionDescriptor action)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[_name]);
    }
}
```

```c#
[HttpPost("bar")]
[ParameterConstraint("someId")]
public IActionResult A([FromForm] string someId)
{
    ...
}

[HttpPost("bar")]
[ParameterConstraint("someData")]
public IActionResult B([FromForm] string someData)
{
    ...
}
```